# BLE Bridge Mode in Linux example

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to use Bluetooth(4.0) on my board to transmit it's Name so any Mobile Application can see it's name and Mobile application initiates the pairing and connection with my Bluetooth.

I have seen some examples of Bluetooth(4.0) scanning nearby devices; For example:- It does scan for Bluetooth Mouser/Keyboard, but in this case Bluetooth(4.0) is in mode where it chooses the device it want to connect while I want it reverse so Any mobile application can see my Bluetooth and gets connect with it and does communication.

How can I put my Bluetooth(4.0) in such mode in Linux? Is there any C library using which I can put Bluetooth(4.0) is the mode where it goes in Bridge mode instead of scanning nearby devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the name of your device like this:

```
hciconfig name "foo"
```

and check your name with:

```
hciconfig name
```

You also have to enable Low Energy advertising for your device to be found by others:

```
hciconfig leadv
```

You can configure your device to accept incoming connections like this (lm for link mode):

```
hciconfig lm MASTER,ACCEPT
```

This way the kernel will accept a connection, even if there are no listening sockets.

Considering you want to do actual communication, you would need to write a program, accepting the connection and sending/receiving data. Just putting your device in a mode where other devices can connect to it isn't really worth anything (because you can't communicate).

The basic principle is to open up an L2CAP socket, with the Channel ID of 4 (for Low Energy), then do standard bind/listen/accept. I suggest you look at the source code of Bluez and the examples.

Comment: Basically I want my bluetooth in listen mode always so any mobile application can see it in it's list and using mobile application it gets connect/pair with RPi and then it press any button on mobile application and it will Turn ON and OFF Relay/Fan/Light.

Comment: Well, I don't really know anything about Bluetooth on Android/iOS, but the part on your RPi will have to be like I described. Activate the right link mode, activate LE advertising, open a L2CAP socket and wait for the connection from the kernel.

Comment: Ok, I think that should workout. Let me try to get if any library for the same is available then it would be more reliable communication.